# Updating Multiple AMP Pages in Google AMP Cache using wildcard

Tags: caching, amp-html

I know there is a way to update the amp content by sending a GET request to the [AMP Cache URL](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping), but I was wondering if it is possible to clear multiple pages' cache by using a wildcard in the cache URL, or do we have to clear one document at a time, which could take a long time if dealing with millions of pages.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does not indicate such method. I'm sure you've read that in the [Remove AMP Content](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping#remove-amp-content).

**Remove AMP content**

> Use the "update-ping" mechanism to permanently remove content from the
>   Google AMP Cache after the content has been removed from its origin.
>   For example, to purge content formerly served at
>   `https://cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/example.com/favicon.ico`, send an update
>   ping request to:
>
> `https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/i/s/example.com/favicon.ico`.
>   Cached content that no longer exists will eventually get removed from
>   the cache; it's just faster to use "update-ping".

Nowhere does it indicate that you can use wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to put a mechanism in place that will update the cache after a page is updated. Our 8 news sites are feed from a CMS. I added a hook into the publish functionality that calls the "update-ping" api after a story is published or republished to makes sure that the page is cached or that the pages cache is up to date.

When a story is unpublished we clear the AMP cache for that page. If we did this by hand it would be a nightmare. Try to tie it into the existing work flow your sites have for updating content. Much more maintainable that way.

Hope this helps!